# Not sure as to where I am redefining str variable

Tags: string, python-3.x, class, oop

I am currently learning the basics of python, I am on my second day of heavy studying and I cannot see as to where I am attempting to call on a string in: margaret_order.cuisine_style(). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
class Restaurant():
    '''Create simple restaurant details.'''

    def __init__(self,name,cuisine):
        '''Initialize name and cuisine type attributes.'''
        self.name = name
        self.cuisine = cuisine

    def print_order(self):
        """Define individual who is ordering"""
        print (self.name.title() + ' is the next individual to order.')

    def cuisine_style(self):
        '''Define the dish that the individual wants to order'''
        print (self.cuisine() + ' Is the type of food that was ordered.')

jimmies_order = Restaurant('Jimmie','Fish Sandwhich')
margaret_order = Restaurant('Margaret','Lasagna')

margaret_order.cuisine_style()
```

The error I get is:

```
  File "/Users/admin/Library/Preferences/PyCharmCE2017.3/scratches/scratch_3.py", line 15, in cuisine_style
    print (self.cuisine() + ' Is the type of food that was ordered.')
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: The error tells you exactly what's wrong. Your `self.cuisine` is not a function. You only use those parenthesis when you call a function. Just remove them. `self.cuisine`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the `TypeError` because in line 15 (`print (self.cuisine() + ' Is the type of food that was ordered.')`), you add a set of brackets after `self.cuisine`, meaning that you are trying to call a string, which is impossible. To fix it, use the following line:

```
print (self.cuisine + ' Is the type of food that was ordered.')
```